# Ruby - sorting hashes into descending order by value

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

I'm trying to solve the following:

"You are given a dictionary/hash/object containing some languages and your test results in the given languages. Return the list of languages where your test score is at least 60, in descending order of the results.

Examples: 
{"Java" => 10, "Ruby" => 80, "Python" => 65}  --> ["Ruby", "Python"]

{"Hindi" => 60, "Dutch" => 93, "Greek" => 71} --> ["Dutch", "Greek", "Hindi"]

{"C++" => 50, "ASM" => 10, "Haskell" => 20}   --> []

I am having trouble sorting into descending order by results. Here is what I have so far

```
def my_languages(results)
array = []
results.each { |a,b| 
results.values.sort.reverse
if b.to_i >= 60
array << a
end
}
return array
end
```

Not the most elegant solution but I am a complete Ruby newbie (and Stack Overflow newbie too - sorry!) Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are kinda mixing the sort and filtering out phases. My solution

1. Filter results with `value >= 60`
2. Sort for values (descending, `-v`)
3. Extract the first element for every array (the language name)

   ```
   def my_languages(results)
     results.select { |k, v| v >= 60 }.sort_by { |(k,v)| -v }.map(&:first)
   end
   ```

Comment: My pleasure :) try a method call at a time and see what returns

Comment: @jordantomiko accept this answer if he answers your question. There is a hollow tic at the left top which you need to click to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
h = { "Java" => 10, "Ruby" => 80, "Python" => 65 }

h.select { |_,v| v >= 60 }.
  keys.
  sort_by { |k| -h[k] }
  #=> ["Ruby", "Python"]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
g = h.select { |_,v| v >= 60 }
  #=> {"Ruby"=>80, "Python"=>65} 
a = g.keys
  #=> ["Ruby", "Python"] 
a.sort_by { |k| -h[k] }
  #=> ["Ruby", "Python"]
```

If you don't care for `-h[k]` two alternative follow.

```
h.select { |_,v| v >= 60 }.
  keys.
  sort_by { |k| h[k] }.
  reverse
```

and

```
a = h.select { |_,v| v >= 60 }.
      keys
a.max_by(a.size) { |k| h[k] }
```

I doubt that one would notice any significant difference in performance among the three.

[Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by), `min_by`, `max` and `min` have been permitted to have an optional argument since Ruby v2.2.

Answer (score 0):

To make it faster I would check minimum value when mapping:

```
hash = {"Hindi" => 60, "Dutch" => 93, "Greek" => 71}

hash.sort.map { |arr| arr[0] if arr[1] >= 60 }.compact

# or imo cleaner

hash.sort.select { |a| a[1] >= 60 }.map(&:first)
```